# Form inputfield in url REST JAX-RS

Tags: html, rest, input, jax-rs, restful-url

I have an REST application running based on JAX-RS

I have an search form something like:

```
<form method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="search">
      <input type="submit" name="searchSubmit">
</form>
```

Then, when i post this form, i want to put this in the request url before submitting to the server-side of the application.

The question is: is this possible and how?
I searched google a lot to find an answer but couldn't find it.

When i submit the form the url becomes MySite.com?search=Foo
Insted of what i really want: MySite.com/search/foo

Comment: What is the purpose of putting form in request url?

Comment: editted my question somewhat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this solely from HTML. You want to do this by using JavaScript.

Change your form to something like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
      <input id="search" type="text">
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Add the jQuery script:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = encodeURIComponent($('#search').val());
    window.location.href = "https://mysitee.com/search/" + search;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of this solution.
I was merely curious if it could be achievieved by something within the form.
Thanks very much for your reaction!